# Post web login form in Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, ecmascript-6, node-fetch

I'm using `request` to post a request to `login.php` with the parameters `uid` and `pwd`, and then using `node-fetch` to read a page that's behind the auth.

```
(async function () {
    request.post(
        'login.php',
        { form: {
            uid: 'username',
            pwd: 'password'
        } },
        (error, response, body) => {
            if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
                console.log(body); // <-- so far so good

                fetch('userdetails.php?id=1234')
                    .then(user => user.text())
                    .then(user => console.log(user));
            }
        }
    );
})();
```

What I get returned from `console.log(body)` from the site is:

> If your browser doesn't have javascript enabled, click  here

That message is shown when I log in normally from a browser. But when I do the subsequent fetch for the user profile, it says I'm not authorized.

Does this have something to with `request` contra `node-fetch`?

Comment: You need to send cookies.

Comment: I tried doing `request = request.defaults({ jar: true }); request.post('...');`, but alas no difference.